# need to explain why checkboxes look funky in Safari

Tags: language-agnostic, safari, communication

Everyone in my office uses Macs and therefore most use Safari.

We have a page that has 30 checkboxes on it, I didn't even do the HTML myself but no matter if I use the html input checkbox with a label or an asp:Checkbox usig the text property for the label my boss is irritated because the checkbox is a little below center on the label.

I can only assume that this is due to Sarari and it's wonky rendering. I doubt there is a fix that wont be rediculously complicated (if there is please let me know). I didn't even do the html myself, I sent it out.

I tried to explain to him that's how Safari "is" but that wasn't acceptable. I googled to see if anyone else had run into such an issue, (I didn't google to hard though, figured I'd just ask you guys). What do I do when hit with an issue like this where he insists something so minor is unacceptable? Am I approaching this wrong? I mean the HTML is perfectly reasonable here it is:

```
<ul>
    <li><asp:CheckBox  CssClass="checkbox" runat="server" Text="Accessories" /></li>
    <li><asp:CheckBox  CssClass="checkbox" runat="server" Text="Art" /></li>
    <li><asp:CheckBox  CssClass="checkbox" runat="server" Text="Athletic Apparel" /></li>
    <!-- etc... -->
</ul>
```

How can I explain this to him a way he will understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wow i didn't even really notice the box was slightly lower than the text until you mentioned it. you can work around that in CSS though:

```
label {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

aligns the text to the checkboxes for me (Safari 3.2.1)

Comment: nice, that makes things even easier.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the Safari and checkbox issue, but I have experienced the situation where the boss or client focuses on something that seems like a non-issue.

The way I handle that is saying something similar to, "I can research this issue and try to find a solution or workaround, but it will probably take me x hours/days.".

I let them make the decision as to if they want me to spend x hours/days working on their issue or use that time to do actual development.